# Need to decrease spawn wait time interval(float) based on time.time value , Instantiation of two objects should decrease by some proportion

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, artificial-intelligence, 2d-games

I am writing a small game where  objects arrives randomly , I need to implement a logic where I can calculate wait interval for next instantiation as per timer.(As game progresses spawn wait time should decrease).

i am trying to spawn objects in the game those object are having lifetime until next appear , player need to tab fingers as they appear and i am trying to instantiate these fingers faster as game progress

only struggling to get mathematical equation to get value for spawnWait based Time.time . i hope i have written it properly now.

[image]

i need equation for graph something like in first Quater(+x,+y) for time.time & spawn wait. although not very much sure.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GameController : MonoBehaviour {
    // Use this for initialization
    public GameObject GoodThumb; 
    public GameObject BadThumb; 
    public int max = 22;
    public float spanWait = 10.0f;
    public static bool gameOver = false;
    Vector3 theNewPos = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(new       Vector3(0,0,11));
    Quaternion  theNewRotation= Quaternion.Euler(0,0,0);

    void Start () { 
        StartCoroutine(spawn());
        OnGameStart();
    }

    void Update () {    
        Time.deltaTime
    }   
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
    //  SpawnRandom ();
        ChooseFinger ();
    }

     public int ChooseFinger()
    {
        return Random.Range (1, 5);
    }

    void OnGameStart()
    {
        //Debug.Log ("Game Started");
    }

    IEnumerator spawn()  {
        GameObject go;
        while(true)
        {
            int randomLoop =  Random.Range(2,5);
            for (int i = 0; i < randomLoop; i++)
            {
                pickRandomFinger();
                go = Instantiate(GoodThumb);
                go.transform.position = theNewPos;
                go.transform.rotation = theNewRotation;
            //  Debug.Log(theNewPos);
            //  Debug.Log(theNewRotation);
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(spanWait);
            }
            pickRandomFinger();
            go = Instantiate(BadThumb);
            go.transform.position = theNewPos;
            go.transform.rotation = theNewRotation;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(spanWait);
            if (gameOver)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void pickRandomFinger()
    {
         int FingerNo = ChooseFinger();
        Debug.Log (FingerNo);
        switch (FingerNo)
        {
        case 1:   // finger1 type bottom good
            theNewPos = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Random.Range(0.0F,1.0F),1.0F, 11));
            theNewRotation =  Quaternion.Euler(0,0,180);
            break;              
        case 2: // finger4 type right good
            theNewPos = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(1.0F,Random.Range(0.0F,1.0F), 11));
            theNewRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0,0,90);              
            break;
        case 3: // finger2 type top good
            theNewPos = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Random.Range(0.0F,1.0F),0.0F, 11));
            theNewRotation =  Quaternion.Euler(0,0,0);              
            break;              
        case 4:   // finger3 type left good
            theNewPos = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0.0F,Random.Range(0.0F,1.0F),11));
            theNewRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0,0,270);             
            break;
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: Please do not add tags to the title. It's a headline, not a Google query.

Comment: Just decrease spanWait per update. And maybe re-factor to spawnWait?

Comment: @catwood, no then it would depend on framerate. You need to figure out what is the citeria to trigger spawn wait reduction and then per update check if that criteria is met. It can be time interval or spawn itself.

Comment: @EdmundSulzanok, good point. Its just the "question" was so vague.

Comment: @fxm i just need some suggestion(some maths equation to derive spanWait using Time.time) on how to calculate "spanWait" as the game progresses (will use Time.time or something similiar).

Comment: @Catwood  , looking for some help on thing as you mention .

Comment: What have you tried already? What did that code do? How was that different from what you wanted it to do? Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for advice on how to present your question in a clear, answerable way. Your current "question" (which doesn't even include a specific question) is far too broad for StackOverflow. There are lots of options, and your presentation doesn't offer any guidance as to which would be appropriate in your specific scenario.

Answer (score 0):

This questions is incredibly vague,
From what I can gather, you want there to be some sort of inverse correlation between the amount of time the user has been in the game and the time between spawns. 
There are a million ways to do this, and the correct answer will be completely dependent on the kind of behavior you want the game to exhibit.

```
timeBetweenSpawns = minTime + max(defaultTime - (timeInGame*constant),0)
```

This ( very simple and generalized ) code will give you a very simple inverse relationship between time spent in game and the time between items spawning. 
You're going to have to think of your own solution and find what works best for your project.